Is there a way to get ESM for one Ubuntu machine without going through Ubuntu? Or at least removing ESM notifications?
I have just one Ubunutu 22.04 server for person use. Would like to get ESM updates just to be safe.
But my countless attempts at contacting Ubuntu through their ESM website are as worthless as screaming into the void.
So I thought there might be another way to enable/get ESM.
On the other hand, maybe for one person server, ESM isn't really as important as I might think? Maybe I can just stop the notifications?

ESM (Extended Security Maintenance), part of Ubuntu Pro, is for systems 5-10 years old. For a 22.04 system, ESM will do nothing before 2027 (5 years). Perhaps there are other Pro services you seek, but you specified ESM. "countless attempts at contacting Ubuntu through their ESM website" suggests that you might be following obsolete instructions. See https://ubuntu.com/pro

The added security benefits (ie. security patches for universe packages) if that's what you're after, are available via Ubuntu Pro.  Extended Security Maintenance allows patches beyond the standard (or beyond five) years.  You can stop all apt notifications (as covered on this site), but it will stop all (including ESM).  Releases in ESM are 14.04, 16.04 & most recently 18.04; it'll be some time before 22.04 goes to ESM

This question is similar to: What are ESM Apps, and how do they relate to Ubuntu Pro?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you found the answer helpful could you please accept it and if you have not already upvote it.

The simple answer is no.
ESM comes from Canonical, and isn't from the Ubuntu community being a key difference the OP has missed.
@guiverc
The added security benefits (ie. security patches for universe packages) if that's what you're after, are available via Ubuntu Pro. Extended Security Maintenance allows patches beyond the standard (or beyond five) years. You can stop all apt notifications (as covered on this site), but it will stop all (including ESM). Releases in ESM are 14.04, 16.04 & most recently 18.04; it'll be some time before 22.04 goes to ESM –
@guiverc

I'll suggest including the detail from comments that back up your argument...   I have no issues with your quoting me (with or without reference too); though I can't speak for user535733.  ESM comes from Canonical, and isn't from the Ubuntu community being a key difference the OP has missed.
